# Solid Conducting sphere is placed inside a metallic shell the conducting sphere is given a charge Both are connected does all charge flow to the shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

[image: The Image contains a question I am unable to answer]

Here the solution says that all the charge goes into the outer shell, is this correct ? If then why ?

Shouldn't the charge transfer happen until the potentials of the outer shell and inner conductor be equal as they are connected ? If then the solution is wrong right ?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is correct. Read about electrostatic shielding to understand why it all goes to the outer surface in this case.

And i think you've some misconceptions about finding potential. When all charge is on outer sphere, both the spheres will have same potential.

Comment: Yea I understood, looks like I had a brainfart, Thanks again.